# jQuery html() doesn't work well in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jquery to request data and then fill them to a table whose id is 'mresholder', it works in webkit and ff but it doesn't work well in IE. It will append those data behind `</table>`.
How to solve this or what's the alternative way to do this?

```
for(i=0;i<length;i++)
{
   song=data.results[i];
   o=$('#mresholder').html();
   $('#mresholder').html(o+='<tr sid='+song.song_id+' aid='+song.album_id+'><td class="sname">'+song.song_name+'</td><td class="sartist">'+song.artist_name+'</td><td class="salbum">'+song.album_name+'</td></tr>');
};
```

Comment: Can we see the related HTML as well, please?

Comment: It sounds like `#mresholder` is another element that contains the table you want to append to rather than the table itself. If that's the case, try editing your search to `$('#mresholder table')`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"sid", "aid" aren't valid HTML attributes. Try data-sid, data-aid

also, change

```
 o=$('#mresholder').html();
 $('#mresholder').html(o+='<tr sid='+song.song_id+' aid='+song.album_id+'><td class="sname">'+song.song_name+'</td><td class="sartist">'+song.artist_name+'</td><td class="salbum">'+song.album_name+'</td></tr>');
```

to

```
$('#mresholder').append('<tr data-sid='+song.song_id+' data-aid='+song.album_id+'><td class="sname">'+song.song_name+'</td><td class="sartist">'+song.artist_name+'</td><td class="salbum">'+song.album_name+'</td></tr>');
```

(.html() to .append())

Comment: If you're using `append`, you don't need `o+=`.

Comment: Note if you use `.append`, don't use `o+=` - you're appending the data directly, not adding it to the prior contents and then appending it all

Comment: @adam forgot that one. removed

Comment: Thank you all. Using append fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `append` instead.

```
$('#mresholder').append('<tr sid='+song.song_id+' aid='+song.album_id+'>'...);
```

Also, check the HTML that you're adding, IE has a problem when adding HTML to a table if it's  not valid.  Try @genesis' suggestion, and change `sid` and `aid` to `data-sid` and `data-aid`, too.

Comment: do you think that's the problem? :)

Comment: @genesis: Not sure, but it's definitely a better way of doing this.