# .html() method of jQuery not working properly in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<h1>
    <span id="T-1">
        <div>1111</div>
        <div><h1>2222</h1></div>
        <div>33333</div>
    </span>
</h1>
```

I have this html code for replicating the issue in IE 9. I am using the following js code:

```
console.log($("#T-1").html());
```

The above code is not fetching the full inner html data. It is fetching some portion of html data. Can anyone have a look at this issue.

Console output is:

```
<div>1111</div><div></div>
```

Comment: What is printed to console? Give the result you see.

Comment: *"It is fetching some portion of html data"* And what, we're supposed to guess what portion that is?

Comment: Note that putting a [`div`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) inside a [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) is **invalid**, the browser is allowed to do whatever it wants to make it right.

Comment: `div` is not a valid child of `span`. The browser will correct this by moving the `div` elements out of the `span` and the `span` will empty then.

Comment: "_not fetching the full inner html data_"...should fetch. IDs has to be unique do you have any other element with same id.

Comment: this is duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418965/jquery-html-doesnt-work-well-in-ie9

Comment: @TBasak make necessary changes in markup, your problem will resolve. i.e :  http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/xbyXeW

Comment: @T.J.Crowder For html5 it is (or will be) defined in which way the browser has to correct an invalid structure: [Why does this new HTML spec legitimise tag soup?](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_does_this_new_HTML_spec_legitimise_tag_soup.3F) `[...]the spec defines (or will define) precisely how to handle and recover from erroneous markup[...]the spec defines algorithms for dealing with syntax errors such as incorrectly nested tags, which will ensure that a well structured DOM tree can be produced[...]`

Comment: your html is invalid.

Comment: you shouldn't use a "–" character in IDs

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting h4 inside h1 and it causing the error which you are getting.
Write valid code like:

make all div to span

```
<h1 id="T-1">
    <span >1111</span >
    <span class="h4">2222</span >
    <span >33333</span >
</h1>
```

checkout his [pen](http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/xbyXeW)

Comment: @t.niese Agreed!, somehow browser manages to go with div inside span but it stops in console when you put h4 inside h1, If you've any doubts I recommend you to try out the same thing! :)

Comment: @VilasKumkar, replace the <h4> tag with <h1> tag in my original html data. It will console this data: <div>1111</div><div></div> (i.e. some portion of original html structure). 

Also if you do the debug in IE9 browser, you can see that Jquery code is not working as expected...

Comment: @TBasak I'm not getting you, could you please elaborate more on this or update your code in question

Comment: @TBasak Dude, "You are nesting h4 inside h1" it doesn't mean that you should try any "h*" tag inside h1